# SwiftUI: matchedGeometryEffect doesn't work during navigation

Tags: animation, swiftui, navigation, hero, matchedgeometryeffect

I'd like to navigate to another screen and have my view animate to its new position on the new screen smoothly (like Hero does). This [article](https://ahmedahmedadam.medium.com/matched-geometry-effect-swiftui-c41f9a7d19cc) suggests it can be done. However this doesn't work at all, I get a regular navigation animation (xcode 15.0 ios17):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var imageNames = ["circle", "cloud"]

    @Namespace var n

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(imageNames) { name in
                    NavigationLink {
                        ZStack {
                            Color.blue.opacity(0.3)
                            Image(systemName: name)
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: name, in: n)
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: name)
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .padding()
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: name, in: n)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
   }
}

extension String: Identifiable {
    public var id: String { self }
}
```

Is it a bug or maybe I'm missing something?..

P.S. I understand in this case I don't need an actual second screen, but the real example is much more complicated.

Comment: You can't use `matchedGeometryEffect` with `NavigationLink`. `NavigationLink` will always use the default animation. However, you can use an if statement to create the hero animation.